# Case insensitive search for an array in couchbase

Tags: arrays, couchbase, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, sql++

I have documents in couchbase like below

```
{
"id": "a32",
"attributes": [
          "R & M Richards",
          "false"
        ]
}

{
"id": "x54",
"attributes": [
          "r & m Richards",
          "false"
        ]
}
```

I want to fetch these two documents in a singe query.
I have created a query (below) but that is only returning one record.

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE attributes IN [["R & M Richards","false"]]
```

How can I ignore the case sensitivity?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options that both use the [`LOWER`](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.6/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/stringfun.html#fn-str-lower) function. First one doesn't use the same array syntax that you're using, it just uses array indexing on attributes.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM `test` t
where LOWER(t.attributes[0]) == LOWER("R & M Richards")
AND LOWER(t.attributes[1]) == "false"
```

The second option uses [`ARRAY` as an operator](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.6/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/collectionops.html#array):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM `test` t
WHERE ARRAY LOWER(x) FOR x IN attributes END IN [[LOWER("R & M Richards"),"false"]]
```